# Configuring Kannel to work with Mblox

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

I have signed up for an account with Mblox. I would like to use Kannel as my SMPP application to send SMS messages to U.S. phone numbers.
I can bind in, but my submits fail (usually with an error code of 0x042A). I am using the following HTTP request (to my Kannel application) to send a test message to my Verizon phone (just using 14085551212 as an example phone number).

http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=14085551212&priority=1&text=Test+message+to+VZW

I am also using the following config file. Has anyone encountered this before and been able to solve it?

My current config file:

```
#---------------------------------------------
# CORE
#    
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
wapbox-port = 13002
admin-password = bar
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSC CONNECTIONS
#
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = smsc1
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
host = "smpp.psms.us.mblox.com"
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = (my account name)
smsc-password = (my password)
port = 3204
enquire-link-interval = 30
system-type = "mbloxclient1"
service-type = -1
interface-version = 34
bind-addr-ton = 0x02
bind-addr-npi = 0x08
my-number = (my short code)
msg-id-type = 0x00
source-addr-ton = 0x03
source-addr-npi = 0x08
dest-addr-ton = 0x02
dest-addr-npi = 0x08
esm-class = 0

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSBOX SETUP
#
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = (my short code)
log-level = 0

#---------------------------------------------
# WAPBOX SETUP
#
group = wapbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
syslog-level = none

#---------------------------------------------
# SEND-SMS USERS
#   
group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
#user-deny-ip = ""
#user-allow-ip = ""

#---------------------------------------------
# SMS SERVICES
#
group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things that need to change. First, you need to include the operator, tariff, and service ID when sending to certain US carriers (such as Verizon and T-Mobile).

To send to Verizon, you'll need to first include a TLV section in your config file with these vendor-specific parameters.

```
#----------------------------------------
# TLV TAGS

group = smpp-tlv
name = SERVICE_ID
tag = 0x1407
type = octetstring
length = 5

group = smpp-tlv
name = OPERATOR_ID
tag = 0x1402
type = octetstring
length = 5

group = smpp-tlv
name = TARIFF
tag = 0x1403
type = octetstring
length = 5
```

Note that this will require installing Kannel version 1.4.4 or higher (within the 1.4.x branch - the 1.5.0 development version does not seem to support TLVs as of this posting).
Once this is set up, you can use the following format to send SMS messages through Mblox with the required TLVs:

http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=14085551212&priority=1&meta-data=?smpp?SERVICE_ID=12345%26OPERATOR_ID=31003%26TARIFF=0&text=Test+message+to+VZW

(You'll have to change the phone number, service ID, and operator ID to the appropriate values.)

For carriers other than Verizon and T-Mobile (i.e., AT&T, Sprint, Cricket, US Cellular, etc.), you should leave out the service ID parameter.
If you are using Sure Route, you will not need the operator ID or tariff parameter.

Good luck! Note that, even with these instructions, it will still likely take a bit of trial and error, and modification to get everything working correctly.

(Disclaimer: Question and answer both provided by an Mblox advocate.)